# CakePHP 3 CakePdf wkhtmltopdf css problems when generating views from shell

Tags: php, cakephp, wkhtmltopdf, cakephp-3.x

This question is about wkhtmltopdf finding CSS files when used from CLI / shell

**Background**

To make fully formed links when generating views from shell (i.e. for email generation), I have configured my bootstrap_cli.php file to define the fullBaseUrl:

```
// in /config/bootstrap_cli.php
Configure::write('App.fullBaseUrl', APPDOMAIN);
```

This is well documented online, and works fine.

I've been using CakePdf plugin with wkhtmltopdf as the engine to generate some PDF reports of some of the pages in my app. Based on reading the docs, links to css need to ensure we are using fullbase.

```
//in /src/Template/Layout/pdf/default.ctp
<?= $this->Html->css('style.css', ['fullBase' => true]) ?>
```

And in the template files, need to request full links

```
// in /src/Template/Pdf/report.ctp
<?= $this->Html->link('test', ['controller' =>'Article', 'action' => 'view', '_full' => true, $id]) ?>
```

This works fine when I am using CakePdf from the browser, regardless of if it's being rendered inline, or saving it to disk.

```
// in /src/Controller/ReportController.php
public function view($id) {

    /** other code **/

    $this->viewBuilder()
        ->setLayout('default') // this looks in Template/Layout/Pdf
        ->setTemplate('/Pdf/report')
        ->setClassName('CakePdf.Pdf');
    }
```

**Problem**

When calling from a shell script, the problem is that the fullBaseUrl setting and the fullBase for the css causes problems, specifically this:

```
// in /src/Template/Layout/pdf/default.ctp
<?= $this->Html->css('style.css', ['fullBase' => true]) ?>
```

Generates this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" src="https://www.app.com/var/www/vhosts/app/bin/css/style.css">
```

I created an alternative layout for CLI and removed fullBase => true

```
// in /src/Template/Layout/pdf/default_cli.ctp
<?= $this->Html->css('style.css') ?>
```

Generates this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" src="/var/www/vhosts/app/bin/css/style.css">
```

The problem now is it's looking in **/bin** and not in webroot.

After some trial and error and reading the [Cake docs](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/configuration.html#general-configuration) I have modified the App.base value in the CLI, but only specifically for this one script, rather than in bootstrap_cli.php:

```
// in /src/Shell/PdfShell.php
class PdfShell extends Shell {

    Public function initialize() {
        parent::initialize();
        Configure::write('App.base.', ROOT . DS . 'webroot');
    }
```

This now causes the style sheet to be in the right place, and everything is working OK.

For completeness, this is how I am generating the file from the shell script

```
// in /src/Shell/PdfShell.php
Public function report($id) {
    $data1 = $this->Controller->get($id);
    $data2 = $this->OtherController->find()->select('stuff');
    $viewVars = compact('data1','data2');

    $CakePdf = new CakePdf();
    $CakePdf->template('report','default_cli');

    $CakePdf->viewVars($viewVars);

    $pdf = $CakePdf->output();
    $pdf = $CakePdf->write(APP . '/Files/Pdf/report.pdf');

}
```

**Summary**

- Normal links within the template file still use '_full' => true, and generate correct links.
- The bootstrap_cli file still has App.fullBaseUrl = 'http://www.app.com'  configured
- I am setting the App.base to point at the webroot so that the view can locate the right css folders when calling wkhtmltopdf from from shell (this is the bit that feels hacky)

**Question**

Is this a bug? Or is it me not understanding how to configure the views correctly from CLI. Is there a better approach?

I know I've solved the problem, but it feels a bit hacky. Specifically pointing App.base at /webroot

Comment: Are you sure that "normal" links generate the correct URL? Normally `App.base` will affect _all_ URL generation.

Comment: @ndm Yes using $this->Html->link with '_full' => true, still generates normal links. I am only getting problems with the $this->Html->css() method. I am still defining App.fullBaseUrl in the cli, it is just appending the full file path after the baseurl if I set fullBase=>true